# performance advantages of using bottle for routing?

Tags: python, performance, architecture, web2py, bottle

I started developing a web application based on the [bottle](/questions/tagged/bottle) web framework a couple of years ago.  I chose Bottle at that time because it was the easiest solution to get up and running fast, and I was just working on building a prototype of an idea I had.  Now, I have several thousand lines of code, and I'm looking to move into production-level solution.

At first I thought that I should move to a full stack framework such as [django](/questions/tagged/django) or [web2py](/questions/tagged/web2py).  As I was moving that direction, I started just using various parts of other frameworks as I needed them.  For example, I implemented web2py's data access layer (DAL) so that I could run my application on [[image]google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine), and now I'm looking to into using web2py's scheduler to manage jobs.  Then, I began to use [cherrypy](/questions/tagged/cherrypy) as a production-level webserver.  I tried the rocket server, but I was getting more errors with it, so I preferred cherrypy over rocket.

I started looking into rewrite my code to fully use web2py's full stack solution; however, the amount of time to rewrite my routing functions to fully move into web2py seems to be significant, and I really wasn't happy with the rocket server.

I really like the simplicity of Bottle, the way that Bottle uses decorator functions to map the routes to the functions, and also the philosophy of extensibility.

*I want to know if there are any specific advantages in terms of performance in using Bottle to do routing, versus any of the full stack frameworks.*

I appreciate anyone's advice on this!

Comment: Hi Wes - this is more of an open ended discussion starter, rather than a question with a definitive answer. It will most likely be closed as "too broad" - unless you can focus it towards a specific **programming** problem you are having. There is no hard and fast definition of "production level software" (this sounds like marketing babble, similar to "enterprise ready").

Comment: I wouldn't really call CherryPy "production-level". uWSGI (usually combined with nginx) is the production-level server of choice for Python web apps.

Comment: **I want to know if there are any specific advantages in terms of
performance in using Bottle to do routing, versus any of the full stack frameworks.** - what do you mean "to do routing"?

Comment: Since I'm using a different web server, the main thing bottle is doing is mapping URLs to views.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to get some advice either to legitimize staying with Bottle as I move towards a more production-level version of the software, but I realized that this can get pretty subjective and not so suitable for asking on SO.  Looks like Bottle + Nginx might be a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this benchmark](http://faruk.akgul.org/blog/python-web-frameworks-benchmark/) and others, Bottle performs significantly faster than some of its peers, which is worth taking into account when comparing web frameworks' performance:

```
1. wheezy.web........52,245 req/sec or  19 μs/req (48x)
2. Falcon............30,195 req/sec or  33 μs/req (28x)
3. Bottle............11,977 req/sec or  83 μs/req (11x)
4. webpy..............6,950 req/sec or 144 μs/req (6x)
5. Werkzeug...........6,837 req/sec or 146 μs/req (6x)
6. pyramid............4,035 req/sec or 248 μs/req (4x)
7. Flask..............3,300 req/sec or 303 μs/req (3x)
8. Pecan..............2,881 req/sec or 347 μs/req (3x)
9. django.............1,882 req/sec or 531 μs/req (2x)
10. CherryPy..........1,090 req/sec or 917 μs/req (1x)
```

But bear in mind that [your web framework may not be your bottleneck](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8836044).

Answer (score 1):

From the creator of web2py, Massimo Di Pierro:

> If you have simple app with lots of models, bottle+gluino may be
>   faster than web2py because models are executed only once and not at
>   every request.

Reference:

[groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/4gB9mVPKmho](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/4gB9mVPKmho)